# how to read/interpret json file to define mysql schema

Tags: mysql, json

I have been tasked with mapping a json file to a mysql database and I am trying to define the appropriate schema a sample of the json file is below

```
"configurationItems":[  
    {  
        "ARN":"",
        "availabilityZone":"",
        "awsAccountId":"hidden from sight ",
        "awsRegion":"",
        "configuration":{  
            "amiLaunchIndex":,
            "architecture":"",
            "blockDeviceMappings":[  
                {  
                    "deviceName":"",
                    "ebs":{  
                        "attachTime":"",
                        "deleteOnTermination":true,
                        "status":"attached",
                        "volumeId":""
                    }
                }
            ],
            "clientToken":"",
            "ebsOptimized":,
            "hypervisor":"",
            "imageId":"",
            "instanceId":"",
            "instanceType":"",
            "kernelId":"aki-",
            "keyName":"",
            "launchTime":"",
            "monitoring":{  
                "state":""
            },
            "networkInterfaces":[  
                {  etc
```

am I right in thinking that the way to do this is essentially wherever there is a bracket /child element there would be a new table eg; configuration items down to aws region would be in a table then configuration through architecture followed by block device mappings etc etc if that is the case then where would the client token through lanch time belong ? many thanks in advance folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That certainly is a way to use it.

It gives a more parent child relation approach to the setup.

E.g.

"blockDeviceMappings":[
                {
                    "deviceName":"/dev/sda1",
                    "ebs":{
                        "attachTime":"2014-01-06T10:37:40.000Z",
                        "deleteOnTermination":true,
                        "status":"attached",
                        "volumeId":""
                    }
                }
            ]

Probably could have more than one devices so it would be a 1 to many relation.